# how to use ruby to assign a default if a value is nil?

Tags: ruby, operators

I have the following to default to 5 if there is not value for `json_element['LIMIT']`:

```
json_element['LIMIT'] = 500
limit           ||=  json_element['LIMIT'].to_i
limit           ||=  5
```

This is the current implementation, but it seems like one line too long.

Comment: The other way around: `var = value || default_value` (i.e. `limit = json_element['LIMIT']&.presence || 5`). Note that you should only use this if `value` cannot legitimately be `false` or `nil`.

Comment: Limit could be nil in which case I want the default to 5. And yes value cannot be nilll

Answer (score 3):

As Amndan says, the idea here is you order things in order of precedence, highest to lowest, left to right, so generally speaking:

```
def do_thing(limit_override)
  limit ||= limit_override || input || DEFAULT
end
```

In your case you're testing a Hash property and converting to integer, so you have options:

```
limit ||= json_element['LIMIT'] ? json_element['LIMIT'].to_i : 5
```

Or just `to_i` whatever you get even if it's ever so slightly less efficient:

```
limit ||= (json_element['LIMIT'] || 5).to_i
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) like this: `limit ||= json_element.fetch('LIMIT', 5).to_i`.

Comment: I don't quite follow the fetch example. Limit and 5 are both parameters in fetch function?

Comment: As in the linked documentation, both `key` and `default` are arguments, yes. The `default` argument can be omitted in which case it's `nil`.